# Is there a `clang++:-Wunused-lambda-capture` equivalent warning in/being developed for GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, compiler-warnings, clang++

#### Background

I sometimes run into code that use the following dummy lambda-capture (instead of e.g. `(void)x;`, `... foo(int /* x */)` or `... foo([[maybe_unused]] int x)` in C++17) in order to remedy an unused variable warning:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    [&x]{}();
}
```

Now, this is not really a remedy, as it passes the warning over from the current scope to the lambda capture instead, but afaik, GCC has no diagnostic to flag this, whereas e.g. Clang ([as of 5.0](http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#major-new-features)) emits the `unused-lambda-capture` warning, if activated.

```
$ clang++ -xc++ -std=c++11 -Wunused-lambda-capture - <<< "int main() { int x; [&x]{}(); }"

<stdin>:1:23: warning: lambda capture 'x' is not used [-Wunused-lambda-capture]
int main() { int x; [&x]{}(); }
                      ^
1 warning generated.
```

In GCC projects, I would if possible be able to catch constructs as the one above without resorting to Clang.

#### Question(s)

- Is there indeed currently no equivalent for GCC?
- If not, is that a feature that is currently planned to be implemented / currently being implemented?

Comment: I would ask that on `gcc@gcc.gnu.org` [mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks, if I don't get an answer here I'll turn to the mailing list (I've never used that reference before).

Comment: Or perhaps on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`

Comment: BTW, you might develop your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to implement that warning, if you really need it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I might have a look, if not mainly for the functionality (I wouldn't say I really need it) for the exercise, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is an open bug report for GCC

> Is there indeed currently no equivalent for GCC?

This is indeed the case, as is covered by the very old but still open bug report:

- [Bug 52281 - No warnings generated for unused captures](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52281)

> If not, is that a feature that is currently planned to be implemented / currently being implemented?

Based on the lack of action on this bug report (reported *and confirmed* in 2012, seemingly not much happening since), this is not something that will likely be added soon.

Comment: "this is not something that will likely be added soon"  - anybody can contribute to gcc

Comment: @M.M Somewhat swiftly caught out of context, slicing away _"Based on the lack of action on this bug report (reported [..] in 2012, seemingly not much happening since)"_ which is the sole argument for _"[...] will **likely** [not] be added soon [...]"_. Given the lack of activity of the ticket as well as e.g. this question, this particular feature does not seem to be on the wishlist of too many developers, and as the original poster of this question, I for one have not (yet) considered contributing to gcc.