# How do I enable a warning for unused lambda expressions in gcc?

Tags: c++, lambda, gcc-warning

The following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/v4Pz6j) has a typo, where I forgot to invoke the lambda expression with `()`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    []{ std::cout << "hello"; };
}
```

Fortunately clang issues a `-Wunused-value` warning for the lambda expression, since it's never evaluated/used.

However gcc does not issue any warning at all. Is there a way to warn about this buggy code when compiling with gcc?

There is a related post about unused lambda *captures* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616378/is-there-a-clang-wunused-lambda-capture-equivalent-warning-in-being-develop) which is similar, but this question is for unused lambda *expressions* themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a \`clang++:-Wunused-lambda-capture\` equivalent warning in/being developed for GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616378/is-there-a-clang-wunused-lambda-capture-equivalent-warning-in-being-develop)

Comment: @HenryLeBerre It's related, but it's for the captures in a lambda, not the lambda itself.

Comment: I've seen some stuff recently indicating coordinated bot attacks. There's no way an actual C++ tag subscriber would downvote this. Not after seeing 95% of the rest of the utter garbage that gets posted here. The fact that the downvotes were quickly reversed (I haven't even seen them), indicates things getting cleaned up, that's all.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik One potential source of transient down votes are mobile users. It's easy to accidentally vote on a question while scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

GCC has warning option `-Wunused` which enables all warnings about unused pieces of code. The latest (trunk) GCC does not warn about the unused lambda with options `-Wunused -Wall -Wextra`. Therefore my conclusion is that there is no way to enable a warning that warns about the shown program in GCC at this moment.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's an open bug report for this? I'd like to avoid opening one if it already exists.

Comment: @cigien I think it should be classified as a feature request. I didn't check if it has been requested before.

Comment: Actually, I would think this should be a feature request as well, but the related post in the question calls it a bug report. Not sure about the gcc bugzilla terminology here :p